# Modular discriminant and ordinary/supersingular points

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $p=2,3,5,7,13$. Denote by $\Delta$ the modular discriminant.

- How can I prove that if $z\in X_0(1)$ is a point of supersingular reduction, then $v_p(\Delta(z))=0$ ?
- If $z\in X_0(1)$ is a point of ordinary reduction, is it true that $v_p(\Delta(z))\geq 0$ ?
- What is the forgetful functor ?
- How the forgetful functor gives an isomorphism between $X_0(1)^{\mbox{ord}}$ and $z\in X_0(p)$ such that $\vert f_p(z)\vert \leq 1$, where $f_p$ is the generator of the function field of $X_0(p)$?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Since $\Delta(z)$ is a modular *form* (as opposed to a modular function), I don't think $\Delta$ can be viewed as a function from $X_0(1)$ to $\mathbf{C}$. So I'm not sure I know what it means to evaluate $\Delta$ at a point of $X_0(1)$.

Comment: That being said, we can still view $\Delta(z)$ has a function from the upper half plane to $\mathbf{C}$, so maybe your question could be reformulated like that?